# wp_nav_menu not rendering properly

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm building a wordpress theme using bootstrap for a little weekend side project and I've been running into an issue with `wp_nav_menu`.

Here is what my code looks like for my header.php:

```
<header class="site-header" role="banner">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array(
                'menu' => 'primary',
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'container' => 'div',
                'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id' => 'navbarDropdown',
                'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
                'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
            ));
        ?>

      </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

According to the documentation `menu_class` should render a ul with the specified class in the array. Instead its rendering a div with those classes, and the container properties seem to be nonexistent. This obviously doesn't play well with bootstrap, any ideas on why this is happening?

Here is what the output looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to verify the menu slug `'menu' => 'primary'` . May be you haven't created a menu that has the slug `primary`. Else just pass the relevant identification. It accepts (matching in order) id, slug, name, menu object.